# android pass onClick event to child

Tags: android, events, onclick

I have a button and as a background, I have an image selector which reacts on press event. The button's text is a spannable string which may contain some links or phone numbers. I linkify those links and phone numbers but how to pass further onClick event to button's text to open browser when I tap over a link?

Answer (score 0):

The button is not designed to work that way. I would use a text view and manipulate background, so when the user cliks on the link the background changes and with some delay changes back and only then open the web link.